# OpenLiteSpeed slow after IP change

Tags: web, litespeed

I tested this multiple times, I created an image of perfectly working OpenLiteSpeed server on EC2, and when I deploy it, it doesn't connect or it connects but extremely slow (it takes around 1 min for page to load).

I just created a simple php page with echo. Nothing too tricky however it does work if I take an image and re-deploy it.

Comment: Please try it in a different region, it happens sometimes due to AWS servers.

Answer (score 0):

check your listener IP address, make sure it's not bind to fixed IP , but rather use `*`